# Send large files to server through low bandwidth connection

Tags: file-transfer, connection, rsync, bandwidth, data-transfer

I'm trying to send large files (> 200Mo) to a remote server with a limited bandwidth using rsync. For now, it doesn't even start sending, only dry-runs succeed.

My tests are working on other servers with higher bandwidths.

Is there any other protocol to share large files between 2 servers for very limited and unstable connections ? I thought about torrent, but it seems less convenient than rsync.